# Need to deploy Windows 8 and Ubuntu to multiple machines

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

Is there a tool that will carry out the deployment of Windows 8 and Ubuntu on about 20 machines, maybe a lot more, including the disk operations as well? I need to be able to specify the percentages or absolute sizes of the partitions to be created, and install a bootloader (grub?).

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be to use something like [FOG](http://www.fogproject.org/?q=node/1) or CloneZilla. I haven't used CloneZilla, but I have used FOG. With FOG, you set up a sample computer the way you want it to be (partitions, LVM, GRUB, Windows, the whole shebang), then upload the image to FOG, and deploy that image on the other systems. You can have multiple images, and a lot of other things which I haven;t tried yet.